# purr::pmap does not keep parameter names

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to execute a function that uses the names of passed parameters with `purrr::pmap`. Unlike `purrr::map` (see below), `pmap` doesn't preserve these names. The below MWE captures the issue:

```
print_names <- function(x) {
  print(names(x))
}

namedVec <- c(nameA = "valueA")
purrr::map(list(namedVec), print_names)
# [1] "nameA"
# [[1]]
# [1] "nameA"
purrr::pmap(list(namedVec), print_names)
# NULL
# $nameA
# NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, in `pmap`, the `.l` argument needs to be a list of listed arguments, but in your function call it's just a list:

```r
print_names <- function(x) {
  print(names(x))
}

namedVec <- c(nameA = "valueA")

purrr::map(list(namedVec), ~print_names(.))
#> [1] "nameA"
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "nameA"

purrr::pmap(list(list(namedVec)), print_names)
#> [1] "nameA"
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "nameA"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>